# how can i fix only the first sectionHeaderView and make other sectionHeaderView be empty in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sectionheader

I have a `UITableView` to implement a function like when I click the cell , I want it column down and show a music player kinda cell with slider and pause button on it, so I think I can use every cell as a section include 2 rows, when I click I reload section and give the second row a different cell style as `playerCell`. but the problem is I only want the first `sectionHeaderView` to fix , when I return nil and 0.0 for the rest sections's `sectionHeaderView` then my first `sectionHeaderView` disappear when I scroll up after the second section scroll up. so how can I fix only the first sectionHeaderView and make other `sectionHeaderView` be empty?

[image]

Comment: Really not sure what you're trying to implement. Can you maybe add a couple of images to illustrate what want to accomplish?

Comment: @remus i'm sorry  i can't add image due to the account limits, do you have Wechat or other tool, i can send you my idea. thanks.

Comment: Just upload them to imgur, add the links to your question, and someone will edit them in.

Comment: @remus image updated!

Comment: I see. Can you just do an `if (row.index == 0) show header` type solution?

Answer (score 0):

If section is 0 then set your section header view's height to Zero, no need to return nil.

Comment: it seems not work, when there is 0 for the second header with no nil view this time, then i scroll up the first headerView disappear too, replace it with a 0 height header and empty headerView that's what i called "the first sectionHeaderView disappear"

Answer (score 0):

Give the required height in the follwing function by comparing sections

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 
  if (section==0)
  {
    //height you want
  }
}
```

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    
    if (section != 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 85*UI_RATE;
} when the second headerView height equals to 0, then i think the 0 view replace the 85 view , then it also disappear!

Comment: check what height you are returning...& try if possible to use reloadSections using the following method

- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation

Comment: the result is  when the first section i return 85 else return 0, and where n when should i call reloadSections method?